# Updating android app on google playstore with alpha, beta track and then production

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have followed following process for uploading first version of my android app on Google Playstore:

1. Internal Test Track (Internal Test)
2. Close Track (Alpha Test)
3. Open Track (Beta Test)
4. Production Track (Uploaded release version)

**For uploading 2nd version:**
Is there any way so I can upload android app version 2 as same as the above process.
If I am going to upload my version2 to playstore alpha track then beta, then it will not affect version 1 in production until I promote version 2 to release track?

Answer (score 1):

From play console you can create a new release for each of those steps. It doesn't delete any release until you tell it to(or not), while creating a new release for production.

Comment: Also, I think that you can retain a version before to create a new release

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can choose to save existing release versions of the app.